# Preserve backend server status when reloading haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Because I have a large pool of https certificates that changes from day to day (massive multitenant application with many domains), I have a script that may reload haproxy at nearly random times. This works fine.

I also set backend servers to MAINT when I am deploying new versions of applications to them. This also works fine.

The trouble is that if the reload happens, any servers that I had set to MAINT status are instead reloaded as READY. This lets customers see waits or even error messages.

Is there a way to preserve the current status of backend servers when reloading haproxy?

Comment: Which version of HAProxy are you using?

Comment: I believe I'm using 1.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure which version you're using, the following needs `HAProxy` `>= 1.6~`:

You might want to have a look at the [load-server-state-from-file](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#load-server-state-from-file) directive, which allows

> seamless reloads of HAProxy.
>
> This directive points HAProxy to a file where server state from previous
>   running process has been saved. That way, when starting up, before handling
>   traffic, the new process can apply old states to servers exactly has if no
>   reload occured. [...]

(That's just an excerpt, for more details follow the link.)

Using this, your config could look like (only relevant parts shown):

```
global
  server-state-file /var/lib/haproxy/server-state
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
  load-server-state-from-file global
```

Your reload command could then look like the following:

```
socat /var/lib/haproxy/stats - <<< \"show servers state\" > /var/lib/haproxy/server-state && systemctl reload-or-restart haproxy
```

That is:

- Connect to the `stats` socket via `socat`, get the states of the servers and / or backends and write to the state file.
- After this, if all went well, reload or restart `HAProxy`.

Comment: This definitely looks like what I am looking for. I miss out on a lot when I don't re-read the documentation every minor release! That wasn't in 1.5 I don't think.

Comment: this does not work for me, i am using version 2.6

Comment: @Farhan did you find a way to make it work?

Comment: @edmz not yet. i tried methods but it does not work. stats are always gone

Answer (score 1):

Since HAProxy 2.0 it's possible to start a "sidecar" process [dataplaneapi](https://github.com/haproxytech/dataplaneapi/) exposing REST API, `haproxy.cfg`:

```
global
  stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin

program api
  command dataplaneapi -f /etc/haproxy/dataplaneapi.yml
```

The `dataplaneapi` is responsible for generating `haproxy.cfg` and reloading `haproxy` itself. Communication between `haproxy` master process and `dataplaneapi` is done via UNIX socket `/run/haproxy/admin.sock`

The `dataplaneapi.yml` looks like this:

```
---
dataplaneapi:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5555
  transaction:
    transaction_dir: "/tmp/haproxy"
  user:
  - insecure: true
    password: verySecretPassword
    name: admin
haproxy:
  config_file: "/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"
  haproxy_bin: "/usr/sbin/haproxy"
  reload:
    reload_delay: 5
    reload_cmd: service haproxy reload
    restart_cmd: service haproxy restart
```

You can then obtain list of frontends using:

```
curl -u admin:$DATAPLANE_PASS http://127.0.0.1:5555/v2/services/haproxy/configuration/frontends
```

A `PUT` request can be used to update the fronend:

```
PUT /services/haproxy/configuration/frontends/{name}
```

See [documentation for more details](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#get-/services/haproxy/configuration/frontends). An update request needs to be wrapped in a transaction:

```
  # fetch current config file version
  GET /services/haproxy/configuration/version
  # start transaction
  POST /services/haproxy/transactions?version={version}
  # make some changes
  PUT /services/haproxy/configuration/frontends/{name}?transaction_id={transaction}      
  # commit transaction, followed by haproxy reload
  PUT /services/haproxy/transactions/{transaction}
```

Another option would be direct communication with HAProxy e.g. via Unix socket:

```
echo -e "set ssl cert /etc/harpoxy/certs/mysite.pem <<\n$(cat ./new_certificate.pem)\n" | \
  socat stdio unix-connect:/run/haproxy/admin.sock
```

Followed by `commit ssl cert ...` command. Available also [since HAProxy 2.0](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/haproxy-runtime-api/reference/set-ssl-cert/).

Comment: This looks excellent. If I was still  at the job that used haproxy I'd definitely use this.